# How do I add a property/value to a Javascript styled enum

Tags: javascript

I am currently using an object to represent an `enum` in javascript. e.g

```
module.exports = {
  doActionA: 'DO_ACTION_A',
  doActionB: 'DO_ACTION_B'
}
```

I do this so I can represent actions and then `switch` them and choose the code the perform.

```
switch action {
  case action.doActionA: \\code
  \\etc
}
```

However I now need to include values with the actions e.g. `doActionA(2)` will perform the action twice. Is there a way to also tag a value with this fake javascript enum I am using? Or is there a better approach to achieve this functionality?

Thanks

Comment: how about doActionA({myParam: 2});

Comment: Is `doActionA` going to map to a function? You currently have it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose having your actions as a set of functions and then invoking them through a "repeater" method.  Something like what I have below.

```js
const exports = {
  doActionA: function() {console.log("ACTION A")},
  doActionB: function() {console.log("ACTION B")}
}

function repeater(repeatableFunction, iterations) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= iterations; i++) repeatableFunction();
}

repeater(exports.doActionA, 2);
repeater(exports.doActionB, 4);
```

If your functions need to take parameters, I made a sample here that uses [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to handle parameters:
https://jsfiddle.net/ghdbc0mL/